# yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: craft\records\Element::canonicalId

Tags: craft3

I updated Craft and plugins to the latest version, and now I cannot save any entries, it throws the following error about unknown property canonicalId:

```
2022-11-10 15:15:45 [-][1][1135ce8218ff6ad66ab545959cff8fe8][error][yii\base\UnknownPropertyException] yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: craft\records\Element::canonicalId in /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php(322): yii\base\Component->__set('canonicalId', NULL)
#1 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/ActiveRecord.php(54): yii\db\BaseActiveRecord->__set('canonicalId', NULL)
#2 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(2610): craft\db\ActiveRecord->__set('canonicalId', NULL)
#3 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Elements.php(785): craft\services\Elements->_saveElementInternal(Object(craft\commerce\elements\Product), true, true, true)
#4 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/commerce/src/controllers/ProductsController.php(301): craft\services\Elements->saveElement(Object(craft\commerce\elements\Product))
#5 [internal function]: craft\commerce\controllers\ProductsController->actionSaveProduct(false)
#6 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#8 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('save-product', Array)
#9 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(293): yii\base\Module->runAction('commerce/produc...', Array)
#10 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(602): craft\web\Application->runAction('commerce/produc...', Array)
#11 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(272): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#12 /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#13 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(23): yii\base\Application->run()
#14 {main}
2022-11-10 15:15:45 [-][1][1135ce8218ff6ad66ab545959cff8fe8][info][application] $_GET = [
    'p' => 'mysiteadmin/commerce/products/products/800296-msa/us'
]
```

**System Report**

```
Application Info
PHP version 7.3.33
OS version  Linux 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64
Database driver & version   MySQL 5.7.40
Image driver & version  Imagick 3.4.4 (ImageMagick 6.9.10-68)
Craft edition & version Craft Pro 3.7.59
Yii version 2.0.45
Twig version    v2.15.3
Guzzle version  7.5.0
Plugins
Admin Bar   3.1.11
AsyncQueue  2.3.0
Bulk Edit   2.0.6
Contact Form    2.5.1
Contact Form Extensions 1.3.2
Contact Form Honeypot   1.0.3
Control Panel Nav   3.0.17
Craft Commerce  3.4.18
Element API 2.8.6.1
mysite  1.0.0
GeoMate v1.3.1.2
Gold SiteCopy   0.8.0
Logs    3.0.5
No-Cache    2.0.8
Queue Manager   1.2.0
reCAPTCHA   1.5.3
Redactor    2.10.10
Redirect Manager    1.1.1
SEOmatic    3.4.41
Shortcodes  2.0.0
Stripe for Craft Commerce   2.4.3
Super Table 2.7.3
Twig Perversion 2.2.0
Wordsmith   3.3.2
Modules
my-module   modules\Module
codeeditor  nystudio107\codeeditor\CodeEditor
verbb-base  verbb\base\Base
Aliases
The following aliases are defined:

@app    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src
@appicons   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/icons
@bower  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/bower
@bower/inputmask/dist   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/inputmask/dist
@bower/jquery/dist  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/jquery/dist
@bower/punycode /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/punycode/dist
@bower/yii2-pjax    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/assets/yii2pjax/dist
@codeEditorEndpointUrl  https://www.mysite.com/index.php?p=mysiteadmin/actions/codeeditor/autocomplete/index
@commerceLib    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/commerce/src/../lib
@config /home/mysite/craftcms/config
@contentMigrations  /home/mysite/craftcms/migrations
@craft  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/src
@craft/commerce /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/commerce/src
@craft/commerce/stripe  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/commerce-stripe/src
@craft/contactform  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/contact-form/src
@craft/contactform/honeypot /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/contact-form-honeypot/src
@craft/elementapi   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/element-api/src
@craft/redactor /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/redactor/src
@craftcommercetests/fixtures    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/commerce/tests/fixtures
@creocoder/nestedsets   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets/src
@dolphiq/redirect   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/dolphiq/redirect/src
@ether/logs /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/ether/logs/src
@mysite/mysite  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/mysite/mysite/src
@goldinteractive/sitecopy   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/goldinteractive/craft3-sitecopy/src
@hybridinteractive/contactformextensions    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/hybridinteractive/craft-contact-form-extensions/src
@jalendport/queuemanager    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/jalendport/craft-queuemanager/src
@lib    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/craftcms/cms/lib
@marionnewlevant/twigperversion /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/marionnewlevant/twig-perversion/src
@mattwest/craftrecaptcha    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/matt-west/craft-recaptcha/src
@mediapath  /home/mysite/public_html/media
@mediaurl   /media
@npm    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/npm
@nystudio107/codeeditor /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/nystudio107/craft-code-editor/src
@nystudio107/seomatic   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/nystudio107/craft-seomatic/src
@ostark/AsyncQueue  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/ostark/craft-async-queue/src
@root   /home/mysite/craftcms
@runtime    /home/mysite/craftcms/storage/runtime
@storage    /home/mysite/craftcms/storage
@templates  /home/mysite/craftcms/templates
@tests  /home/mysite/craftcms/tests
@topshelfcraft/wordsmith    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/topshelfcraft/wordsmith/src
@translations   /home/mysite/craftcms/translations
@ttempleton/nocache /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/ttempleton/craft-nocache/src
@vaersaagod/geomate /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/vaersaagod/geomate/src
@vendor /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor
@venveo/bulkedit    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/venveo/craft-bulkedit/src
@verbb/base /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/verbb/base/src
@verbb/cpnav    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/verbb/cp-nav/src
@verbb/shortcodes   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/verbb/shortcodes/src
@verbb/supertable   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/verbb/super-table/src
@wbrowar/adminbar   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/wbrowar/adminbar/src
@web    https://www.mysite.com
@webroot    /home/mysite/public_html
@yii    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2
@yii/debug  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-debug/src
@yii/queue  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src
@yii/queue/amqp /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/amqp
@yii/queue/amqp_interop /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/amqp_interop
@yii/queue/beanstalk    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/beanstalk
@yii/queue/db   /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/db
@yii/queue/file /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/file
@yii/queue/gearman  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/gearman
@yii/queue/redis    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/redis
@yii/queue/sqs  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/sqs
@yii/queue/stomp    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/stomp
@yii/queue/sync /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-queue/src/drivers/sync
@yii/redis  /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-redis/src
@yii/swiftmailer    /home/mysite/craftcms/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/src
Requirements
PHP 7.2.5+ 
PDO MySQL extension 
MySQL 5.5.0+ 
MySQL InnoDB support 
MySQL timezone support 
Sensitive folders should not be publicly accessible 
Ensure @web alias is explicitly overridden 
Reflection extension 
PCRE extension (with UTF-8 support) 
SPL extension 
PDO extension 
Multibyte String extension (with Function Overloading disabled) 
GD extension or ImageMagick extension 
OpenSSL extension 
cURL extension 
ctype extension 
ini_set calls 
Intl extension 
Fileinfo extension 
DOM extension 
iconv extension 
Memory Limit 
Max Execution Time 
password_hash() 
Zip extension 
JSON extension 
proc_open() 
proc_get_status() 
proc_close() 
proc_terminate() 
allow_url_fopen 
ignore_user_abort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the Sections for the new site seems to have fixed it.